# unable to upload an Image to firebase storage from nativescript -angular

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, image-upload

I am following the template given at https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-master-detail-ng for android.
All functionality is working fine with my own repository at Firebase.
The issue is with Image Upload.
I get an error :- **JS: Error in firebase.uploadFile: Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: metadata cannot be null**
The Image path that i select is :- "/data/data/org.nativescript.myappname/cache/nsimagepicker/1587561257744.jpg"

I am out of options now. what should i check? Any links to consult/ examples?

Thanks

Comment: You may be missing the metadata parameter, refer the [Firebase Storage](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/STORAGE.md#uploadfile) docs for more info.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add `[SOLVED]` to the title or edit a solution into your question. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). If you don't want to do that, you can either wait for someone else to answer or you can delete the question. You can learn more about how this site works by reading the [help] pages.